# EAFP vs LBYL when dealing with dirty inputs

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose you have to work with data with the following format :
{'letter': 'a', 'age': 3} and you know letter should always be a single character.

You know some of the inputs you have doesn't verify this property (letter is sometimes longer). Suppose you know how to clean it but you know you can't be 100% sure that you cleaned everything (there could be problem with the age value for example). Should you clean it anyway before doing anything with it ?

If I clean the input, I know I won't have to deal with this problem later and put my code into try/except block handling problems coming from bad letters. But it's contrary to EAFP principle, isn't it ?

Should I clean my inputs ?

Comment: EAFTP is about giving requirements to the code that understands it and is best able to handle it. We recommend EAFTP because this is important (so many [TOCTOU bugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use) would be avoided if people took it seriously), but this is still a judgement call! Put the verification where the verification most naturally wants to be. This is specific to your codebase.

Comment: Generally speaking, though, you should make verification coincide with a change of shape (in statically typed languages one might say "change of type" instead). This is important because it erects a boundary between verified and unverified values. Often this change of shape is the most natural place to "ask for forgiveness"; try to convert and handle the case where it has not.

Comment: Note that it is a common misconception that EAFTP implies using exceptions. This is not true; failure can just as effectively be expressed through the return value. Again, choose whatever makes the most sense for your use-case.